# Reloading Document Qlikview every morning at a specific time

Tags: qlikview

How can I reaload my document qlikview every morning at 7am.

Help is appreciated,

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to schedule batch file in Windows TaskScheduler.

The batch file should look like this:

`"C:\Program Files\QlikView\qv.exe" /R "C:\path\to\my\qvw\MyApp.qvw"`

And add this batch file to the task.

If you have Qlikview Server/Publisher just let me know. I'll share the way how to achieve this there.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but there is a way much easier with run macro,

Comment: Thank you for your response, but there is a way much easier with macro run, there is the link: https://luciancotea.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/auto-reload-every-10-minutes-desktop-client/,  the function is : =if((Now()-ReloadTime())*1440 >= 10, vTriggerReload+1, 0) for 10 minutes; the think that i want to specify time and to be every day.

Comment: Im not recommending you going this way. Yes, it is an option to do it but there are few drawbacks. It use the function `Now()` which pools the OS every second to get the current time. So you will have a constant CPU usage (very small ofc). Also if you are using `today()` function somewhere - by default this function return the day when the document is open (you can change this but need to pay attention every time when its used in the document) [1/2] ....

Comment: [2/2] If you just leave the document open and make reload with macro, today() will always be the same day. What if the machine get rebooted or someone close the app by mistake? To use this macro you need to have the document constantly open. Using Task Scheduler (or similar software) you can be more safe that the document will be reloaded. In general i can suggest you to avoid macros as many as you can. Especially if you plan to publish the document in QV Server. Not all macros are working there.

Comment: It's very clear, Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: @Stephan Stoichev, yes I have Qlikview Server/Publisher, share with me the way to do it ! thank you